# Не получается центрировать веб страницу при ее отдалении.

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Не получается центрировать информацию страницу хочу, что бы выглядело как в примере. Заранее прошу прощения за такой нубский вопрос, я только учусь. Если будут еще советы по улучшению кода и адаптивной верстке буду рад их прочитать.

[image: Пример]

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
body {  
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Futura PT", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* для корректного отображения текста на всех экранах*/
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /*для нормального скроллинга*/
}
.header-top {
   height:40px;
    background: #ffffff;
    line-height:40px;    
}    
nav {
  display:flex;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;  
}
nav .nav-title {
  color:#686868;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  margin-left: 68px; 
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}
nav .navigation {
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  color: gray;
  flex-grow:1;
}
nav .navigation li {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 16px
   /*странно, но нижняя тень работает только так, если поставить ; она будет отображаться некорректно*/   
   margin-bottom: 11px;
   margin-top: 25px;
         
}

nav .navigation li.selectable:hover {
box-shadow:0 -2px 0 0 #1c76bc inset;
}

nav .navigation li.left {
    flex-grow:1;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
/* Подписаться на розсылку*/

nav .navigation a{
  color: #686868;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 19px;  
}


/* настройка кнопок*/
/*кнопки без адаптивного дизайна, потом доделаю*/

main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
}

main .top-slide{
  background: url(https://www.stihi.ru/photos/malenkajaskazka.jpg);
  width: 1240px;
  height: 376px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%; 
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box-white{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 292px;
  height: 292px;  
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 42px;
  margin-left: 860px; 
  margin-right: 86px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}

.first-p{
  width: 262px;
  height: 37px;
  color: #5497cc;
  font-family: "Futura PT";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 16px;  
  margin-bottom: 243px;
  margin-left: 14px; 
}

.cool-p{
  width: 262px;
  height: 59px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Futura PT";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;   
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 185px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.third-p{
  width: 262px;
  height: 86px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Futura PT";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 119px;   
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 87px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.read-more-p a{  
  width: 95px;
  height: 37px;
  color: #5497cc;
  font-family: "Futura PT";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 253px;   
  margin-right: 51px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 146px;
}
.read-more-p img{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 257px;   
  margin-right: 31px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
  margin-left: 247px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>shtooooo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <header>
  <div class="header-top">
     Header top
  </div>
 </header>

  <nav>
     <div class="nav-title">Блог</div>
     <ul class="navigation">
       <li class="selectable"><a href="#">Для бізнесу</a></li>
       <li class="selectable"><a href="#">Для людей</a></li>
       <li class="left"><a href="#">Підписатися на розсилку</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
  
 <main>
  <section class="top-slide">
   <section class="box-white">
    <p class="first-p">Головне</p>
    <p class="cool-p">Тут буде також дуже крутий заголовок</p>
    <p class="third-p">Integer quis interdum libero. Praesent et ante et dolor tincidunt semper. Nulla id nibh vel metus molesti</p>
    <p class="read-more-p"><a href="#">Читати далі</a><img src="img/arrow.png" alt="arrow"></p>    
   </section>
  </section> 

  <div class="lust-news and search">
   <p class="lno">Останні новини</p>   
  </div>


 </main>



 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: используйте <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.